# Insert characters before and after a char

Tags: c#, string, text, substring

from my previous questions you understand that I'm making a translator. There is a string called Text(eg. "This is one of my best projects, so I'm going to finish it.") and what **I want is to insert "%" before and after "," - comma and  "." - dot** so how can I do it. I've tried to do it by using for loop but no success.

Comment: Post the code you have tried!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.You can do a simple replace for this, no need to even resort to regular expressions.

```
var string1 = "This is one of my best projects, so I'm going to finish it."
var string2 = string1.Replace(",", "%,%").Replace(".","%.%);
```